# ngx slick carousal not working inside the ngx-bootstrap accordion in angular7?

Tags: angular, accordion, slick.js, ngx-bootstrap-accordion

i have added the ngx -slick-carousal inside ngx-bootstrap accordion and tabs,tabs also present inside accordion, but if i add it in outside of accordion its working.how to add inside the accordion? if need to initialize how to do?

```
<accordion [isAnimated]="true">
  <accordion-group heading="Title 1">
    <tabset class="spot-tab">
      <tab heading="Stress1">
        some content
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Stress2">
        <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel first" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideflipbookConfig">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
          <div class="full-width relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
        </ngx-slick-carousel>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

Add (click)="toggleAccordian()" in accordion tag

In .ts
Once refresh the slick slider then it will load automatically

```
toggleAccordian() {
  $('.carousel').slick('refresh');
}
```